# When does shorthand ASPX statement execute?

Tags: asp.net

In an ASPX page I have the following statement

```
<%=someObject.value%>
```

But nothing is displayed. At which stage of the page cycle does that code run at?

Comment: that would be at render.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please show me someObject which is created at code behind.